# File not found when using PHP

Tags: php, windows-server-2003, configuration

Problem:

PHP is not working right.  My html file asks for a name and then calls 
the PHP will display a "Hello" message.

What is happening is on the htm page I am putting in my name and hit go
then the browser shows website/Drop2.php and I get 404 error  saying
page not found.
It is like the htm page is not really getting to the PHP file.

Environment:

- Software loaded and verified
- Win Server 2003
- IIS 6.0
- PHP 5.4
- VC9 x86
- FastCGI
- WinCache 1.3
- Visual C++ Redistributable files for X86

PHP has been tested and works from command prompt
All FastCGI changes have been made per documentation

My configuration looks like this

- c:\Inetpub\wwwroot    htm and php file
- c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\PHP    PHP software

I have installed all the above software, set up the following:

1. Extension   .php    c:\Intepub\wwwroot\PHP\ext\php5isapi.dll
2. Added index.php to my doucments in IIS
3. Added to php.ini both and extension_dir=c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\PHP\ext
       and extension=php_wincache.dll
4. Added Web service Extension for PHP ISAPI
5. Added to Path - c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\PHP

Here is htm code for Drop2.htm:

```
<html>
<head>
<Title>Form</Title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Enter your name</h1>
<form method="post" action="C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Drop2.php">
<input type="text" name="me">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>

here is PHP code for Drop2.php:
<html>
<head>
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "<h1>Hello " . $_POST["me"] . "</h1>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to run live on my server try.
www.sloventhal.com and click on 3 to execute this code

Comment: I tried change htm code to  http://localhost/Drop2.php but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 5):

```
<form method="post" action="C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Drop2.php">
```

`C:\` is not a URL, it's a path.

```
<form method="post" action="Drop2.php">
```

would be better, assuming the files are in the same folder.

Comment: Also, on the live example, you're linking to localhost which is wrong.

Comment: I changed it to what you said.  Both htm and php are in the same directory but still get the 404?

Comment: @user2945923 You say you've got a `PHP` folder for the PHP code. http://loventhal.homeip.net/Drop2.php appears to 404 but http://loventhal.homeip.net/PHP/Drop2.php seems to be a non-404.

Comment: @ceejayoz I get a 404 for both, it's just drop2.php is a custom 404 whereas the other one isn't.

Comment: loventhal.homeip.net/PHP/Drop2.php is still a 404 just display my 404 page which I use.  The loventhal.homeip.net/Drop2.php gives a page not found

Comment: Is there something in PHP config that I am not setting right?

Comment: You shouldn't have to set anything at all. This should work with default PHP. Can you verify the location of Drop2.php and Drop2.html in wwwroot?

Comment: yes both Drop2.php and Drop2.htm are in the wwwroot file system

Comment: PHP is also in the wwwroot file system

Comment: @user2945923 It's interesting to me that http://loventhal.homeip.net/Drop2.php and http://loventhal.homeip.net/Drop2.html show **different** 404 pages.

Comment: that should be Drop2.htm  no l at end.  the htm file will work fine but the php still gets file not found

Comment: @user2945923 I know it's `.htm`. However, the fact that the `.html` and the `.php` URLs both have 404 errors but **different** 404 errors is interesting to me.

Comment: I agree it is strange.  I have been fighting this problem for almost a week now and finally change to as simple a code test as possible to eliminate any other issues.

Comment: @user2945923 Have you considered starting on a hosted server somewhere? My guess is you've got something wrong with the configuration, not the PHP code itself. Running a server is a big bite to chew when you're just trying to learn a language. Even something like XAMPP would probably be much better.

Comment: It's gotta be a config issue. The code runs fine.

Comment: that is what I have concluded but have no idea what in the PHP config isn't right.  The IIS has been up and working fine for several years now.

Comment: so where do I go from here to try and resolve it?  Any ideas?

Comment: @user2945923 I'd start learning *either* PHP **or** server config, not both at once. Hard to isolate issues that way. Install something like XAMPP if you want to learn PHP and not worry about the server stuff.